# Why do horizontal and vertical alignment use different terms for centering (center vs middle)?

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment, text-align

`text-align` has `center` as possible value and `vertical-align` has `middle` as possible value.

As far as I know `center` and `middle` have no different meaning. So why there is a different term for the same thing?

Maybe someone here can tell me the reason of it.

Comment: `center` refers to horizontal centering whereas `middle` refers to vertical centering

Comment: I know this already, but the terms alone mean the same thing and I wanted to know why they name it different. Maybe because it is better to have unique propertie values?

Comment: In the context of CSS, they do not mean the same thing.

Comment: they do not mean the same thing because the W3C give them that meaning. better worded question would be: why the W3C has chosen to name these things different. I think it could be because of possible confusions.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a better way to word it. I think that `middle` is a more effective way to describe vertical centering. The word `center` implies absolute center(vertical and horizontal), but when you're aligning something vertically, it's not necessarily aligned to the absolute center, it's just in the "middle" of the element(half way between the baseline and the top of the element), it can still be left or right justified which is not technically "center."

Comment: It may be a remnant from when both horizontal and vertical alignment were specified by the same attribute `align`, for instance the `<img>` element had `align=middle` and the `<div>` element had `align=center`. It would have been confusing if both were using `center` for different properties! See official W3C docs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#adef-align-IMG) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align).

Comment: For contrast, W3C SVG's horizontal and vertical for [`transform-origin`](https://docs.w3cub.com/svg/attribute/transform-origin) both use `center`. So `left center` and `center top` are valid. Implying that `center` and `middle` actually mean anything distinct horizontally vs vertically due to a historical artifact are post hoc justifications.